# Stop handler if no more files are found

Tags: java, android, handler, runnable

I am doing a project in android.I am trying to get the names of files one by one in Toast .My problem is how to stop the handler if there are no more files available

Here :

```
private void finder (){
final Handler h= new Handler();
final Runnable r= new Runnable (){ public void run (){ h.post delay(this,1000); scanner(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); } }; h.post delay(r,1000); }

public void scanner(File 
sdcard){
File[] files = 
sdcard.listFiles();
if(files!=null){
for(int i=0; i<files.length; 
i++){
if(files[i].isDirectory()){
scanner(files[i]);
}else{
if(files[i].getName().ends 
with(".mp3")){ 
  Toast.makeText(this,files[i].getName(),1000).show();
 break;
  }
 }
}
 }
}
```

Comment: It would be a lot of help if your code wasn't left justified :)

Comment: I'm not gonna look at that code too hard, but just put a `finished` boolean in your `Runnable`, and set it when you're out of files. Make your `run` method check `finished` before `post`ing itself again

Comment: @AnthonyCathers sorry sir but I don't get you

Comment: @cactustictacs How can I do that sir :')